# Error response while writing file more than 4 MB to Azure Fileshare using SAS url

Tags: azure-storage-files

We are using SAS url (REST API) and HTTPS PUT method to call a write operation (range operation as per Azure Technical name) on Azure file storage. We are successful in executing this operation and write data to the file for any data size less than 4MB. If the data exceeds over 4 MB, Azure file storage is returning below error response.

We did use MuleSoft and Postman applications to execute this operation. Error response is same accross all applications.

Error
Code : RequestBodyTooLarge
Message : The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit. RequestId:2bbfe0e9-001a-0050-0291-87df64000000
MaxLimit : 4194304

Can anyone help or through some light to understand the issue and resolution.

Comment: Since `PUT Range` has the limitation for the range up to 4MB in size, could you provide more details about your scenario, then we could provide better solutions for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Error Code : RequestBodyTooLarge Message : The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit. RequestId:2bbfe0e9-001a-0050-0291-87df64000000 MaxLimit : 4194304

As mentioned in this official [PUT Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-range) about the **Range or x-ms-range**:

> For an **update operation**, the range can **be up to 4 MB in size**. For a clear operation, the range can be up to the value of the file's full size.
>
> Calling Put Range with the Update option performs an in-place write on the specified file. Any content in the specified range is overwritten with the update. Each range submitted with Put Range for an update operation may be up to 4 MB in size. **If you attempt to upload a range that is larger than 4 MB, the service returns status code 413** (Request Entity Too Large).

Here is my test, you could refer to it:

[image]

Based on my understanding, if the range is larger than 4MB, I assumed that you need to break your data into a buffer (up to 4MB in size), then you could invoke `PUT Range` Rest API to update your data with the specific range in order or in parallel.